# Is there any benefit of working with an Iterator over a List

Tags: scala

Is there any benefit of manipulating an Iterator over or List ?

I need to know if concatenating 2 iterators is better that concatenating to List ?

In a sense what the fundamental difference between working with iterator over the actual collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Iterator` isn't an actual data structure, although it behaves similar to one. It is just a traversal pointer to some actual data structure. Thus, unlike in an actual data structure, an `Iterator` can't "go back," that is, access old elements. Once you've gone through an `Iterator`, you're done.

What's cool about `Iterator` is that you can give it a `map`, `filter`, or other transformation elements, and instead of actually modifying any existing data structure, it will instead apply the transformation the next time you ask for an element.

"Concatenating" two `Iterators` creates a new `Iterator` that wraps both of them.

On the other hand, `Lists` are actual collections and can be re-traversed.

Comment: So in short, the only advance is that it is lazy ?

Comment: It's not so much about advantages vs. disadvantages in an abstract sense. It's about the differences, which only become advantages and disadvantages depending on what you want to do. `Streams` are also lazy, but unlike `Iterators` they can be retraversed. The question is, what is it you wanna do?

Comment: Actually I was just wondering because I am having to concatenate list in my spark code and spark itself work with iterator. When u finish a mapPartition, you should return an iterator over your data. So I transform back to iterator. I initially convert the spark iterator to a list because I need to batch the processing of each partition anyway. By batching I mean I have an a service that takes a batch of data and produce an output. I can’t process élément by element. The reason i am concatenating is that that batch processing is applied to groups of the partition.

Comment: It short, transform the iterator over a partition into a list, group, and apply a batch process on each group. The output of each batch process is actually a string of many json object that I convert back to a list. Hence the output of a batch process to each group is a list. Then I concatenate all of them and produce an iterator as per spark requirements. I was just thinking if I should put some effort in ovoiding list and all and stay as much as possible in the iterator land. Granted, when converting to a list you parse the all list. But that is just at the beginning. Cost should neglectable

Comment: I am not familiar with Spark and it sounds like you should probably create a new question showing us the actual code you've written, if you still need help.

Comment: @MaatDeamon, I think you generally want to try to avoid converting the `Iterator` in `mapPartition` if possible. The additional processing time might not be huge (relative to everything else), but you might be having to allocate a lot of memory depending on the size of the objects in the `List`. Also, if you're persisting that data, then Spark is going end up holding two copies of the data, at least for a time -- this doesn't seem so nice. In any case, with a bit of thought I find I can usually avoid converting the `Iterator` in `mapPartitions` to a `List`.

Comment: A major difference is that an entire `List` must exist in memory, whereas an `Iterator` can generate one element at a time on the fly.